# Where to host Selenium Script for Client

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have been making one automation script for client to make his various task to automate. Now script is done and working fine. I have created script in My local pc.

So what is best way to deliver it to client so he can run it whenever he want. I thought to install Eclipse, JAVA and Selenium JARs to client pc and import my project there.

Is there any other good way? I am looking for something where Me and client can run script any time we want. Something global place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Continuous Integration service, for example:

- jenkins - https://jenkins-ci.org/ *In a nutshell, Jenkins is the leading open source automation server. Built with Java, it provides hundreds of plugins to support building, testing, deploying and automation virtually any project*
- circleci - https://circleci.com/ *Start shipping faster, build for free using CircleCI today.
  You have a product to focus on, let CircleCI handle your continuous integration and deployment.*
- http://travis-ci.org travis-ci is also very popular - *Easily sync your GitHub projects with Travis CI and you’ll be testing your code in minutes!*

For example of 10 others see:

http://www.yegor256.com/2014/10/05/ten-hosted-continuous-integration-services.html

Comment: Thanks for help. Jenkins was in my mind but wanted to confirm. Thanks again.